# Every object is pink, even textureless planes

Tags: rendering, texturing

Got a project with some objects done by a freelancer, opened it on my PC and every object is pink in a rendered view and on the final render.

[image]
*(On a picture a background plane is selected)*

I know, that the pink color in Blender means missing textures, but this project had no textures, even a simple plane on background, that should be white, is pink. The guy who did that project only used standard texture nodes, such as Wave Texture.

[image]

In a new project, everything is fine.

Tried switching render settings from GPU to CPU, from Cycles to Eevee, tried installing previous Blender versions, did not help. Probably some small button that I have pressed unintentionally.

ELP

Comment: I would guess that the problem is with your world shader.  Can you switch the shader editor from object to world and screenshot the nodes?

Comment: Solved! Yeah, the world shader was missing. Deleted it and everything is fine now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.